# Correct way of connecting Websocket events to update my React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

So I'm primarily a C++ backend developer but I'm learning React on the side and I have this really simple file to use websockets.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

var serverMessage = "";
var webSocketReady = false;

function connect() {
   webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:3000/ws")

   webSocket.onopen = (event) => {
     webSocketReady = true;
   };

   webSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
     serverMessage = JSON.parse(event.data);
   };

   webSocket.onclose = function (event)
   {
     webSocketReady = false;
     setTimeout(function() {
         connect();
       }, 1000);
   };

   webSocket.onerror = function (err)
   {
     console.log('Socket encountered error: ', err.message, 'Closing socket')
     webSocket.close();
   };
}

connect();

export default function MyTestComponent({
  ...props
}) {
   const [varThatNeedHooks, setVar] = useState({});
   if (!webSocketReady)
   {
     return (<h1>Could not connect to server retrying ...</h1>);
   }
   else if (serverMessage == "")
   {
     return (<h1>Waiting for message from server ...</h1>);
   }
   else
   {
     // do stuff with varThatNeedHooks
   }
}
```

I'm looking at the react documentation and I realized this way that I'm connecting the websocket to MyTestComponent has got to be wrong. But I'm not sure what is the "React" way of hooking up the events from the websocket to change what gets rendered. Anyone have any good documents or examples I can follow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically you'd make `serverMessage` and `webSocketReady` part of the React state so that when they are updated it triggers a component rerender. Use an `useEffect` hook to manage the socket instance.

Example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function MyTestComponent({ ...props }) {
  const [varThatNeedHooks, setVar] = useState({});
  const [serverMessage, setServerMessage] = useState("");
  const [webSocketReady, setWebSocketReady] = useState(false);

  const [webSocket, setWebSocket] = useState(new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:3000/ws"));

  useEffect(() => {
    webSocket.onopen = (event) => {
      setWebSocketReady(true);
    };

    webSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
      setServerMessage(JSON.parse(event.data));
    };

    webSocket.onclose = function (event) {
      setWebSocketReady(false);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setWebSocket(new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:3000/ws"));
      }, 1000);
    };

    webSocket.onerror = function (err) {
      console.log('Socket encountered error: ', err.message, 'Closing socket');
      setWebSocketReady(false);
      webSocket.close();
    };

    return () => {
       webSocket.close();
    };
  }, [webSocket]);

  if (!webSocketReady) {
    return <h1>Could not connect to server retrying ...</h1>;
  } else if (serverMessage == "") {
    return <h1>Waiting for message from server ...</h1>;
  } else {
    // do stuff with varThatNeedHooks
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch this is 99% of what I need honestly. But I have a question, my original code has the onclose try and reopen the websocket after waiting 1 second. I may not understand useEffect enough but does that functionality still exist here?

Comment: @user1289479 I was wondering about that part specifically. Would need just a little refactor. I'll update.